# Changing Project Type from "Executable" to "Static Library" in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way in the Eclipse CDT gui to change a project type after you have created it?  I initially created a new C project in CDT as an executable on error.  I would like to convert this project to a static library.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to go to project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Artifact Tab. There you can change the artifact type to static or shared library.